# What is better for land vehicles, recycled ABS or virgin ABS? Which would absorb more energy in case of a collision?

Tags: automotive-engineering

According to [this](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Farah-Kamil/post/Any-book-or-publication-about-impact-of-recycling-in-developing-countries/attachment/59f978e5b53d2f3ade4c0292/AS%3A555788185288704%401509521637286/download/Mechanical+and+chemical+recycling+of+solid+plastic+waste.pdf) *[p. 15]* paper (or rather the papers it cited), recycled acrylonitrile butadiene styrene (ABS) has inferior impact strength and ductility compared to virgin ABS. Is it a good thing or a bad thing for vehicles? Would vehicles made from rABS (or a 50/50 blend, say) be safer or less safe than vehicles made from virgin ABS? Which would absorb more energy in case of a collision?

> Of these polymers, the most effectively recycled is ABS. However, ABS is sensitive to degradation both during its lifetime (UV
> and oxygen induced) and during processing (thermomechanically induced). The mechanisms involved are both chain
> scission and crosslinking (Arostegui et al., 2006; Peydro et al.,
> 2013; Scaffaro et al., 2012), as shown in Fig. 21. Additionally, volatile components (mainly styrene derivates) may develop during
> the product lifetime due to environmental degradation. These are
> freed during the reprocessing of the ABS, potentially leading to
> void formation in the recycled ABS extrudate (Arnold et al., 2009)
> and reduction of impact strength (Bai et al., 2007).
> This degradation will inevitably lead to inferior mechanical
> properties of rABS, when compared to virgin ABS. **Impact strength
> and ductility are foremost among these** (Bai et al., 2007; Boldizar
> and Moller, 2003; Brennan et al., 2002; Peydro et al., 2013).

Comment: IME (non automoive), ABS is a marginal material for any outdoor or industrial application. Not great chemical resistance, needs a lot of additives for stabilization vs UV and wide temperature range (as in automotive)... otherwise needs to be covered up with another material, which seems to be how it's used in bumpers

Comment: It's not opinion-based

Answer (score 2):

ABS with no *regrind* material in it will be superior for the bodywork panels of a vehicle. But for the *bumpers* and the energy-absorptive material inside them, the regrind material is probably adequate- since its job is to be crushed on impact, not spring back, and be cheap to replace.

Comment: Would it, a bumper from rABS, absorb more or less energy than a bumper from virgin ABS?

Comment: I do not know. -NN

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev you should be able to find the characteristics of the material from the data sheets. You have those don't you.